# Метод clear удаляет содержимое всех ArrayList, а не одного

Tags: java, arraylist

Имеется три "глобальных" списка, с которыми я веду работу:

```
public List<View> allEds;
private List<View> allEds2 = new ArrayList<>();
public List<View> allEdsdop = new ArrayList<>();
```

В процессе работы я заполняю `allEds` и делаю его бэкап (то есть просто присваиваю этот список другому, чтобы эти значения хранились не в одном списке, а в двух) в `allEds2` и в `allEdsdop`.
Перед присваиванием всех значений `allEds` в `allEds2`, методом `clear` я очищаю `allEds2`:

```
allEds2.clear();
allEds2 = allEds;
```

В этот момент в `allEds` и `allEdsdop` уже есть список некоторых значений. Но после применения `clear()` все три списка очищаются, и количество элементов в них становится равно `0` (`allEds.size()=0`).

Почему это происходит, и как это исправить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

После первого такого "бэкапа" (`allEds2 = allEds;`) `allEds2` ссылается на тот же список, что и `allEds`. В результате очистка `allEds2` приводит и к очистке `allEds`.

Копию списка нужно делать так:

```
allEds2 = new ArrayList<>(allEds);
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы для этих целей не воспользоваться `Map` коллекциями подобные:
`HashMap`, `ConcurrentHashMap`, `etc`? ключ => значение.

```
final Map<String, List<View>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Будет легче работать с записываемыми коллекциями, при этом легко можно перезаписать или удалить, отчистить, что угодно.

Comment: А это не усложнит ли задачу? Мне, по сути, надо просто время от времени очищать списки и все, чтобы данные туда не дублировались